# Importing Data from a JS file into Svelte

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte

I'm new to Svelte and I'm trying to import an object I have in a separate JS file into my App.svelte file to be used. When I try and import the data, I get the whole function instead of the return value when I try and console log it or it return object Object. For simplicity sake, I just made date.js file that returns the date and I've tried the 2 export method up top, neither have worked.

date.js

```
module.exports = getDate
function getDate(){
  date = Date()
  return date;
}
```

In the App.svelte file I have:

```
<script>
    import { getDate } from './date.js'
    let date = getDate()
</script>
```

I noticed that in my node/express app, the return type of getDate is an Object and in the Svelte app the return type is a Number and I'm not sure why this is. Also the date.js file is location in the src folder so that isn't an issue. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I got it to work by removing the {} brackets from getDate import. I only had them there because I was trying to follow another example that had them. The other example was trying to import a js Class but I'm not sure why they were needed. Thanks!

Comment: You are missing something on the export/import mecanism >> check the docs ! ;) https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export